# How to save crontab -e on nano editor by python3 subprocess

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi3, nano

I want to set cronjob on Raspberry Pi 3, initiated by python subprocess, but I am not sure how to code pressing keys `ctrl` + `x` ,then `y` ,and then `enter` to save it. I am using nano as a text editor, and the below is my code so far.

```
p = Popen(["crontab -e"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdin.write("@reboot python test.py")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with the following bash command without using vi editor:

```
(crontab -l ; echo "0 4 * * * myscript")| crontab -
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, your question is more about how to work with nano editor.
after you open crontab script with

```
crontab -e
```

it will open with nano editor.
then you should add what you want at the end of this file:

```
@reboot python3 test.py
```

(if test.py is not in the current directory, you should write the full path to the file. for example /home/pi/Desktop)

To save your file in nano:

**press crtl o** (to say you want to write the file). then

**press Enter** (to say you want to overwrite existing file). then

**press ctrl x** (to exit nano)